# Need help in 2017 R2 - 17.200.0401 modern UI Sitemap

Tags: acumatica

I have created some new categories and added my screen under that category, do we have an option to put these newly created categories and sitemap structure into customization project or else we need to recreate manually in each instance.
Group 1 and Group 2 are the new categories I have created and linked some screen under it.
[image]

Comment: As far as I know, it is not currently possible to include Modern UI changes in a customization project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if we uncheck entry screen checkbox for GI screens, we are able to get the entry form in both Title Menu and as well as in Menu Item also. But, as these default Acumatica GI screens are in Hidden folder, they are not exposing in Add Menu Item popup, so I moved to Help folder

Answer (score 2):

The steps are:

1. Add the page to the classic SiteMap (SM200520)
2. Add classic sitemap entry to your customization project sitemap section and publish it
3. Add your page to modern UI
4. In customization project editor SiteMap section click 'Reload from Database'

[image]

The Reload from Database step should add the Modern UI sitemap entry.

You can check if the modern UI were packaged in the customization project items (Menu->File->Edit Items). Project items of type SiteMapNode that deploy to modern UI will have XML elements/attributes prefixed with 'MUI' (ModernUI).

Comment: Thanks HD_ACUMATICA, works like charm, but may i know how i can add existing screen also, because i need to add some default screens and GI also under my newly created category, i could not able to see all the screenIDs in the sitemap in customization project. Please help me

Comment: I haven't tested it but this might work. Modern UI needs a classic sitemap custom entry. You can create a new entry in classic sitemap that points to the original Acumatica page, in effect duplicating the page in sitemap. When you go to add that page in modern UI you will see 2 of them, add the one that you created instead of the default system one and follow the same procedure. In effect the modern UI sitemap entry piggy back on the classic one so if you don't have the classic sitemap custom entry in the customization project there's no sitemap item available to put the modern part.

Comment: Hello, I have duplicated the customer screen and given a new name and added to the classic sitemap, but in modern UI, am able to get that newly created screen in ADD TITLE menu but not in ADD MENU ITEM options. Is their any other way to achieve it.

Comment: Please correct me if am wrong, i believe their are some screen which we can add only as TITLE item but not as MENU ITEM example Customers screen (AR303000)

Comment: Not too familiar with MUI system but new inquiry screens were introduced with it. The philosophy is to have the TILE open on New document (AR303000) and have the MENU ITEM open on these inquiry screen that ends with PL (AR3030PL). For system pages it seemed to be by design. Pages that don't have an equivalent PL suffix probably don't have that behavior. You can see the same pattern with Sales Order, Shipment, Invoices and so on. I think it was made to help the user, opening on a drilldown was deemed more practical then new document. To enforce that design pages  that have a PL are hidden.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of John's answer and HB_ACUMATICA's answer seems to be the more complete answer. The steps in HB_ACUMATICA's answer works, except if the classic Sitemap item is contained in certain folders (in my case, Finance/AR/Configuration/Manage), then it won't show up on the modern UI in the list of items to choose. If I moved it to the Help folder, then I could choose it.  Anyone know what the criteria is for including an item in the modern UI item choice list?